# Vue.js table updating component data without re-rendering whole component on selected filters

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, setinterval

I have a single page dashboard application. I've been playing around with `setInterval` which works quite well for just updating the data without reloading the page. I put the setInterval function within `mounted()`, not sure if it best belongs there but works okay.

However! This SPA has a ton of filters. You can search, you can select dropdowns, you can sort, on and on. Say the initial page load has 1000 rows and you use the search bar to narrow it down to one row/one result. Now setInterval runs and it will re render all 1000 rows. This is the method (defined in `methods: {}` section that initially loads the data and the method used in `mounted()` with `setInterval`):

```
getData: function (arg1, arg2) {
  API.getSomeData(arg1, arg2).then(resp => {
    getTicketData(resp.data);
    this.$data.loading = false;
  });
}
```

Is there a way to account for the filters when it comes to the setInterval piece?

Any and all insight is appreciated.

Comment: Re: "*Now setInterval runs and it will re render all 1000 rows.*"- So you're saying that you don't want it to rerender all 1000 when 999 of them are filtered out, and only render the 1 instead?

Comment: Can you show what your filter code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be overwriting the same data property when you fetch data from the API and when you filter on it. If that's the case, you should use a computed property to display the filtered records to the user instead.

```
computed: {
  tableRows() {
    if (this.filters)
      return this.filter()

    return this.apiData
  }
```

Where `this.filter()` will filter down `this.apiData` without overwriting its contents. Then you can iterate over `tableRows` in your template (e.g. `v-for="row in tableRows"`) to display those to the user.

If you want to remove some of this logic from your Vue component, you might consider using a Vuex store to both fetch/update from your API and also to calculate the filters.

```
this.$store.dispatch('fetch_on_interval', { interval: 1000 })
this.$store.dispatch('set_filters', { ...filters })
this.$store.getters('table_data')
```

Your getter would check the filters and return whatever is relevant. Vuex getters can be used in computed properties too.